# I want to resubmit page with submitted form detail when I am in submitted page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form. When I submit the form, I will be redirected to another page.
I want to resubmit my submitted form when I click a button.
Just like when we press the `Ctrl + F5` in the browser and it asks our browser if we resubmission page.
How can I do this?
Thanks

I didn't try anything because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: If you _just_ want the same effect as Ctrl + F5 would have, then do a `location.reload()`.

Comment: Yes, it is. @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it .

```
location.reload()
```